# Coverflow animation for listview in gallery

Tags: android, listview, gallery, scrollable

I am implementing a gallery containing series of vertical scrolling listviews. I have googled for similar implementation and i got coverflow widget specified here : http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html But it only deals with images converted as bitmaps for scaling and rotating in customized gallery view. As my implementation needs vertically scrolling listviews, i need some help.

Can i reuse this code replacing images with my listviews? or is there any customized gallery which suits my requirement. Any help would be appreciated.

Attached safari bookmark page for reference. I want view like this where i should be able to scroll each column as vertically scrollable listviews and horizontally scrollable gallery.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a Look at my answer

There are three classes should be added in your activity packge

1  **[CoverAbsSpinner.java](http://pastie.org/3878170)**

2  **[CoverAdapterView.java](http://pastie.org/3878173)**

3  **[CoverFlow](http://pastie.org/3878165)**

Call thease classes  from your activity . The way to call CoverFlow from activity

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;

public class CoverFlowActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CoverFlow coverFlow;
        coverFlow = new CoverFlow(this);

        coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter =  new ImageAdapter(this);

        coverImageAdapter.createReflectedImages();

        coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);

        coverFlow.setSpacing(-15);
        coverFlow.setSelection(8, true);


        setContentView(coverFlow);

        //Use this if you want to use XML layout file
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //coverFlow =  (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);


    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;

        private FileInputStream fis;

        private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                R.drawable.a,
                R.drawable.b,
                R.drawable.c,
                R.drawable.d,
                R.drawable.e,
                R.drawable.a,
                R.drawable.b,
                R.drawable.c,
                R.drawable.d
        };

        private ImageView[] mImages;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            mImages = new ImageView[mImageIds.length];
        }
        public boolean createReflectedImages() {
                //The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
                final int reflectionGap = 4;


                int index = 0;
                for (int imageId : mImageIds) {
                    Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                            imageId);
                    int width = originalImage.getWidth();
                    int height = originalImage.getHeight();


                    //This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.preScale(1, -1);

                    //Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
                    //We only want the bottom half of the image
                    Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);


                    //Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
                    Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width 
                      , (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888);

                   //Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
                   //the image plus gap plus reflection
                   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
                   //Draw in the original image
                   canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
                   //Draw in the gap
                   Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
                   canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);
                   //Draw in the reflection
                   canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null);

                   //Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
                   Paint paint = new Paint(); 
                   LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0, 
                     bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, 
                     TileMode.CLAMP); 
                   //Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
                   paint.setShader(shader); 
                   //Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
                   paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN)); 
                   //Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
                   canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, 
                     bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint); 

                   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);
                   imageView.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(120, 180));
                   imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                   mImages[index++] = imageView;

                }
                return true;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //Use this code if you want to load from resources
            //ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
            //i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
            //i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
            //i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);           
            //return i;

            return mImages[position];
        }
         /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views 
         * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */ 
         public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) { 
           /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */ 
             return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset))); 
         } 

    }

}
```

The output just like

[image: preview of coverflow]

Comment: this example helped me to create cover flow. but on swipe to to change to the next image the gap between images is getting reduced. So can you please help me to resolve this issue.